# Form Validation in Multi step form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a multi step that has an input validation. Instead of displaying a toast for the empty input error, I want to show an error text under the input field. Just like this:

[image]

Apparently it's not good practice to use a toast message for these kind of errors.

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    businessName: "",
    businessEmail: "",
    currency: "",
    industry: "",
    businessDescription: "",
    useCase: "",
    organisationType: "",
    website: "",
    businessPhone: "",
    country: "",
    billingName: "",
    billingEmail: "",
    addressState: "",
    addressCity: "",
    addressStreet: "",
  });
```

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
    if (step === 0) {
      if (formData.businessName === "") {
        toast({
          title: "Error",
          description: "Please provide a business name",
          status: "error",
          position: "top-right",
          duration: 3000,
          isClosable: true,
        });
      }
      if (formData.businessEmail === "") {
        toast({
          title: "Error",
          description: "Please provide a business email",
          status: "error",
          position: "top-right",
          duration: 3000,
          isClosable: true,
        });
      } else {
        setStep(step + 1);
      }
    } else if (step === 1) {
      if (formData.website === "") {
        toast({
          title: "Error",
          description: "Please provide a website",
          status: "error",
          position: "top-right",
          duration: 3000,
          isClosable: true,
        });
      }
      if (formData.businessPhone === "") {
        toast({
          title: "Error",
          description: "Please provide a registered phone number",
          status: "error",
          position: "top-right",
          duration: 3000,
          isClosable: true,
        });
      } else {
        setStep(step + 1);
      }
    } else if (step === 2) { ............. and so on.
```

This is my form in one of the steps:

```
export default function Account({ formData, setFormData }) {

return (
  <Input
     placeholder="Business Name"
     name="businessName"
     onChange={(e) => {
     setFormData({
      ...formData,
      businessName: e.target.value,
     });
     }}
     value={formData.businessName}
     type="name"
  />

<Input
     placeholder="Business Email"
     name="businessEmail"
     onChange={(e) => {
     setFormData({
      ...formData,
      businessEmail: e.target.value,
     });
     }}
     value={formData.businessEmail}
     type="email"
  />

......... and so on.
)
```